# update smtp url relay

Tags: debian, postfix

I changed my provider 2 weeks ago, since I can't send mail from PHP.

In log I have:

`Aug 20 23:13:27 paul sm-mta[2814]: v7KHRmbx031864: to=<contact@xxx>, ctladdr=<www-data@xxx> (33/33), delay=03:45:39, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=2011044, relay=mxb.ovh.net., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with mxb.ovh.net.`

ovh.net is my previous provider.

I use postfix. I updated `relayhost` postfix/main.conf and reboot it.

But the relay in log message doesn't change.

The server is under Debian OS.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your providers [documentation](http://help.ovh.com/EmailConfiguration) before blaming them. The `mxb.ovh.net` is not supposed to work as an outgoing SMTP relay as it's a backup MX for incoming mail.

> Name of the outgoing server: `smtp.yourdomain.com` or directly, our server name: `ns0.ovh.net`

With a VPS you don't probably even need a relay as you can host your own MTA connecting receiving MTAs directly.

Then, `sm-mta[2814]` is a process of Sendmail. Postfix configuration changes doesn't affect Sendmail.